# How do I layout my web page using CSS so that the right-hand column doesn't wrap?

Tags: html, css

On most of my web site (http://sellsbrothers.com), the right-hand column where I keep the search bar and the ads stays on the right-hand side as I intended. However, on some pages (http://www.sellsbrothers.com/Posts/Details/12670), it doesn't. How do I fix the ones that don't? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks fine on my machine - generally though, I have this problem if the combined widths including padding and margins are too large.  This can sometimes happen when the contents of a div forces it to be larger than you have specified, so you have to take this into account.  Try experimenting with the padding/margin/width of each element.

Comment: is there a way to restrict the content of a div so that it doesn't overflow the boundaries of the div?

Comment: OK, I pulled in the content and that made it stop wrapping, but what's with the damn scrollbar?!

Answer (score 0):

I checked it with firefox 3.6.2 and was able to see both search box and the ads on both pages. You can check for yourself at **[Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/)**. It is very possible that on certain browser it might not behave it should.

Two Pages at Browsershot:

**[Result](http://browsershots.org/http://sellsbrothers.com/)**